# Log file is not being generated in log4j2 in spring boot application

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, apache-camel, log4j2

I know there are a lot of post similar to this one, but no solution inside them worked for me. I have created a simple java code in eclipse and I am getting the output in the console screen, but the log file is not getting generated.

**log4j2.properties**:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file.append=true
appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

loggers=file
logger.file.name=Processors
logger.file.level = trace
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = trace
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger= INFO, file, stdout
```

**dependencies**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**java code**:

```
public class GetRoomsProcessor implements Processor{    
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GetRoomsProcessor.class);   
    
    public void process(Exchange xchg) throws Exception {
        
        
    ...
  
  String statusCode = String.valueOf(response.statusCode());
    if (statusCode.equals("200") || statusCode.equals("201")) {
    ...

          rooms.setRooms(listdata);
          Gson g = new Gson();  
          String str = g.toJson(rooms);  
          //System.out.println(str);
          logger.info(str);
          logger.warn("This is a warn message");
          logger.trace("This is a trace message");
         xchg.getIn().setBody(str);
        }
```

What do I need to do to write logs to a file?
Thank you

**update**:
I tried to add also the following dependencies and still did not work:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.16.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: When you started up your spring application, do you know if log4j found the log4j.properties file? I believe you have not initialized log4j properly.

Comment: Hello @MinhKieu, don't you think that it is reading the properties file if it is displaying the logs in the console?

Comment: Besides I have the following warning appearing in red at the start at the application I don' t know if it is related to my case: ```SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.14.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.14.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
...
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]```

Comment: Because of the **Log4j2 vulnerability CVE-2021-44228** you should **upgrade asap log4j-core to 2.16.0** (you might also upgrade log4j-api to the same version)!

Comment: hello @howlger, I already did by adding this to pom: ```<log4j2.version>2.15.0</log4j2.version>``` which overrides older versions

Comment: Better upgrade to 2.16.0 (in which the class causing the trouble has been removed) since 2.15.0 is still vulnerable in some cases. Please also update your question to avoid that someone copies the dependency with the vulnerability.

Comment: Run your app with the `-Dlog4j.debug` flag. This will print out information about which log4j properties file was found and loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by updating these two values in `log4j2.properties` file:
`property.filename =D:\\Users\\User\\MyFiles\\Apache Camel github\\ChatServiceProject\\logs\\propertieslogs.log`
`appender.file.fileName=${filename}`

Comment: May be you can provide a relative path instead of absolute path. 
So something like,
property.filename = logs/propertieslogs.log
This should work on any path and not just the D:\\...

Comment: @Jitendra it did not work for me